# Storing list items into memory

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I wanted to know if this is possible to achieve the following in `Visual Studio`.

1. There is a `list box`.
2. The user clicks on an item in the list box and a `textbox` appears.
3. The user can fill data in the `textbox`.
4. The user clicks on another item in the list box then the previous data gets stored in memory and the text box appears blank for the new data.
5. When the user clicks save then it stores everything in the database.

Let me know if this is possible because the other option would would be to save each date as the user clicks on each item.

Comment: Why don't you want to store it in the database as soon as the user clicks on a different item? It is safer and also more intuitive. Apart from that, of course it is possible to store it in a collection. You could for example use a `Dictionary(Of Object, String)` where the key is the item and the value is the text.

Comment: I have a request from the user that everything saves when they click update. If this isn't possible then I better tell before I go done this crazy road. I know it is better to save everything in the database before they click on another item.

Comment: There's no reason you can't do what you've listed above if that's what the client wants.  Just create a class/object that mirrors your loaded data, update it when the form controls are modified, then update the database from the object when they click update.